# Magento2.4.1 __construct() must implement interface Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface, string given

Tags: magento2.4.1

I am using magento2.4.1 on php 7.3 I am facing this error right now.

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: 

Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\PushNotification\Grid\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 5 passed to Ens\PushNotification\Model\ResourceModel\PushNotification\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface, string given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
Exception in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131
```

And here is my code  in
app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/PushNotification/Grid/Collection.php

```
<?php

namespace Ens\PushNotification\Model\ResourceModel\PushNotification\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Ens\PushNotification\Model\ResourceModel\PushNotification\Collection as PushNotificationCollection;

/**
 * Class Collection
 * Collection for displaying grid of sales documents
 */
class Collection extends PushNotificationCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AggregationInterface
     */
    protected $aggregations;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool
     * @param mixed|null $mainTable
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $eventPrefix
     * @param mixed $eventObject
     * @param mixed $resourceModel
     * @param string $model
     * @param null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }
```

Do you have any idea why i am getting this error?

Comment: In your parent::__construct add `$storeManager` after $eventManager.

Comment: I did not worked.

Comment: Recompile, this issue shows up when you have a previously compiled interceptor with different construct arguments. Or set your environment to developer mode.

Comment: Issue fixed. Thank you @RahulBarot   for reply. i removed these two lines and problem get fixed. (1)\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       (2) \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,

Comment: Good to hear. Whenever you are extending a class and defining constructor you need to pass all arguments to parent constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run php bin/magento setup:di:compile command and check.

when we add new dependencies in constructor and without run di:compile command in frontend we face this type of similar issue.

please run command and fix issue if found.